Puppetserver unable to retrieve facts from nodes
When I perform puppet lookup fqdn --node <AGENT-CERT-NAME> --explain, I get the following error: Error: Could not run: No facts available for target node: agent.foo.lan
My puppet agent already had performed a successful puppetrun before, so actually, my puppetdb must got facts.
All certificates are signed

What's in the Puppet Server logs?
